# Initial state of Cell State and HiddenState from LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to understand whats the initial state of cell state and hiddenstate of a LSTM in keras for example at the start of the training, or after `model.reset()`.

Are they just random numbers between 0 and 1 or something like that. I tried searching in the Code from keras, but couldn´t figure out how its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out that both are initialised with zeros.